Правильно ли я понимаю, что такое объектный код?
Допустим, имеется исходный .cpp код. При процессе компиляции данного кода мы получаем объектный код (как я понял, это машинный код). А при процессе линковки мы объединяем множество объектных файлов в единый .exe исполняемый пакет. Прошу меня исправить и прояснить данные понятия и процесс.

Все верно (только надо помнить, что после компиляции каждый файл объектного кода  настроен на некоторый фиктивный адрес (обычно 0), в процессе линковки эти адреса перенастраиваются в соответствии с местом размещения объектного кода во всем исполняемом модуле, а также весь исполняемый модуль может быть перенастроен на заданный адрес)

@avp ссылочка по теме

по данной теме рекомендую посмотреть семинар https://youtu.be/44uQ6Q3qHNQ?si=A_acsvIIjIvy1hXH

@αλεχολυτ, если вы привели ссылочку в качестве намека, что неплохо бы сделать этот комментарий ответом, то я не возражаю
